# Order of $\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-t^{\alpha}) \cos(zt) dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $\alpha > 1$. The function $$f(z) = \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-t^{\alpha}) \cos(zt) dt$$ is entire. Proof: write $g(z,t) = \exp(-t^{\alpha}) \cos(zt)$. Given $a \in \mathbb C$, $\partial_a g$ exists and $\partial_a g(z,t) = -t \exp(-t^{\alpha}) \sin(at)$ and this is integrable with respect to $t$. Hence, $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a) = \int_0^{\infty} -t\exp(-t^{\alpha}) \sin(at) dt$.

I am wondering how to find the order of $f$. I wrote $f$ as a power series but the coefficients are just too much for me to handle. Is there a clever way to do this? If not, how to compute the order? I am okay if you can just handle a specific case (say $\alpha = 2$).

Comment: If $g(z)$ is an entire function of order $\alpha$, can you prove $\int_{0}^{z}g(t)\,dt$ is an entire function of the same order?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just tried, but I don't see how to do this. Any link/hint?

Comment: @J.Doe Write $g(z)$ as a general power series, integrate termwise, and plug the coefficients into the limit.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thanks. Notice how I mentioned that I already did this (in the last paragraph) but I couldn't handle the limit.

Comment: I was replying to your reply to Jack's first comment.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt oh okay. I did this as well; I had $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{ \ln(n+1) - \ln |a_n|}$$ I am not sure how to compute this.

Comment: You can rewrite it as$$\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}-\frac{\ln|a_n|}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}\right)^{-1}=?$$

Comment: Observe that $$\exp(-t^\alpha)\cos(zt)=\exp(-t^\alpha)\Re[\exp(izt)]=\Re[\exp(-t^\alpha+izt)]=\Re\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-t^\alpha+izt)^k}{k!}\right]$$ Maybe you can try to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\,f^{(n)}(0)\right|\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}t^n \exp\left(-t^{\alpha}\right)\,dt =\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{\alpha}\right)$$
implies that the order of $f$ is bounded by $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: Can you please add some details? (e.g. an outline of how to prove that this inequality implies what you claim). I am not very familiar with the $\Gamma$ function. In fact I only know its definition, $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$, and what it does to integers.

Comment: Doesn't the fact you mention tell us, rather, that the order of $f$ is bounded by $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}$?

Comment: @J.Doe: you are correct, answer fixed. Airy functions are defined by a similar integral with $\alpha=3$ and they have order $\frac{3}{2}$, indeed.